# Quick Debug about reading words

Tags: java

I have this code and I receive an error when I run the program. Am I doing something wrong with this?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class countLines {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int count = 0;
        int word = 0;
        File f = new File("file.txt");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(f);
        while(input.hasNext()){
            String words = input.next();
            word++;
        }
        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            input.nextLine();
            count++;
        }
        input.close();
        System.out.println("Number of Line: " + count);
        System.out.println("This file has " + word + " words.");
    }
}
```

Comment: "An error" is very vague. What error? Help us out a bit. It looks like you try and read from input, close it and then read from it and close it again though... which is wrong.

Comment: I guess there really isn't an error, I just can't run the word count and the line count at the same time. Eclipse kicks me out of the console tab and brings me to the debug tab.

Comment: Ok, I did that but it still does one or the other. It will count the words and then give me 0 for lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first `while` loop, you are reading your file, then you `close` it. Then, in your next `while` loop you attempt to read from the file again. This will trigger an error, since the file is closed!

Comment: Do I take one of the close statements out? or both?

Comment: Or simply take the first `.close()` off.

Comment: But you need to go to the start of the file again

Comment: @Eduardo +1, I missed that.

Comment: Ok, reopened the file, still it counts one or the other.

Comment: can you please edit your code to reflect the change?

Comment: Try adding `input = new Scanner(f);` in between the two whiles, and put back the `close` before it (also in between the two whiles)